# where does the space between a FontAwesome icon and an A tag comes from?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Live page: http://xrsand.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=92&Itemid=305

Every mosaic has two lines under the image, each line has a FA icon in the front of it. The first line is a link, while the 2nd is plain text. I am using `fa-fw` to keep the icon at same size and to align the texts. But there seems to be a white space between the icon and the `A` tags that comes from nowhere, in order to keep texts align, I have to manually add a space between the icon and the text for the 2nd line. For demonstration purpose, I omit this space for the 1st mosaic, you can see the texts are not aligned in it.
I think I encounter this problem before, and that was without FA, I can recall it involves some mysterious space between `span`s, but I can't reproduce the scenario. So probably this has nothing to do with FA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the indentation you used when rendering the content. It is considered as a single space by the browser:

```
<h2 class="sprocket-mosaic-title"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-fw"></i>
                <a href="/index.php?option=com_k2&amp;view=item&amp;id=90:2015-02-05-15-33-34&amp;Itemid=305">                      同圆共享中国梦                 </a>                </h2>
```

Try to remove it when render the page and put the `<i>` tag together with `<a>` tag. It should solve the issue.

```
<h2 class="sprocket-mosaic-title">
     <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-fw"></i><a href="/index.php?option=com_k2&amp;view=item&amp;id=90:2015-02-05-15-33-34&amp;Itemid=305">同圆共享中国梦</a>
</h2>
```

The same happens when you add many spaces to a content:

```
   <a href="anything">         It will be rendered with a single space</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! That indeed is the source of problem.
 However, the space is generated by Joomla(when input the title, I didn't input any space, Joomla put some spaces before and after it), I am perplexed why Joomla would do this.